# comparison of CouchDB .net libraries

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, couchdb

There are several discussions already here but they are older and non exhaustive.

I am looking for a comparison of CouchDB c# libraries.  Specifically, feedback on the ones listed on the [CouchDB website](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_C%23) .

1. [LoveSeat](http://github.com/soitgoes/LoveSeat)
2. [Relax](http://github.com/arobson/Relax)
3. [Divan](http://github.com/foretagsplatsen/Divan)
4. [SharpCouch](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse)
5. [DreamSeat](http://github.com/vdaron/DreamSeat)

Any feedback on these (or others) - real world experience would be great.

Comment: I would strongly disagree that this is not a constructive question.  There are many technologies out there we should be able to discuss the pros and cons of them freely.  There are many similar popular questions on stackoverflow.  Please re-open this question for the community.